# pycharm syntax error for correct sqlalchemy code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm getting a syntax error for the following statement, the problem section being `(Player.name == data["name"]) | (Player.account == data["account"]))`:

```py
player_from_db = db.session.execute(
    select(Player).where(
             (Player.name == data["name"]) | 
             (Player.account == data["account"])
    )).scalar()
```

This is the error:

> Expected type 'Union[ColumnElement[bool], _HasClauseElement, SQLCoreOperations[bool], ExpressionElementRole[bool], () -> ColumnElement[bool], LambdaElement]', got 'Union[bool, int]' instead

But the clause clearly has two bool expressions. Help appreciated!

Comment: Not sure here, but have you tried replacing the pipe with an or_?  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/operators.html#:~:text=Operators.__or__()%20(Python%20%E2%80%9C%7C%E2%80%9D%20operator)%3A

Comment: Please try with or_() instead of pipe https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_

Comment: It isn't a `SyntaxError`, it's a typing error. Without knowing which version of SQLA that you are running, and the definition of `Player` and `data` it's not possible to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?